# Unable to retrieve result from httpRequest in Parse Cloud function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I am running a Parse httpRequest inside a Cloud function, which I am calling from a different Parse job. I cannot figure out how to retrieve the result value / success value from the Cloud function from where I called it within the Cloud job.

Here's the code for the cloud function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("maps_request", function(request, response) {
  var maps_url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json';
  var origin = request.params.origin;
  var destination = request.params.destination;
  var waypoint = "via:" + request.params.waypoint;
  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: maps_url,
    params: {
      origin: origin,
      destination: destination,
      waypoints: waypoint,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      durationInTraffic: true
    },
    success: function(directions) {
      var time = directions.data['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration']['value']
      time = time / 60.00
      response.success(time)
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error("Shit broke.")

    }
  })
});
```

And the code for the call in the Cloud job:

```
var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
      promise = Parse.Cloud.run('maps_request', {
        origin: String(driverOriginAddress + " " + driverOriginZip),
        destination: String(driverDestinationAddress + " " + driverDestinationZip),
        waypoint: String(driverDestinationAddress + " " + driverDestinationZip)
      }, {
        success: function(results) {
          console.log("Results: " + results)
        },
        error: function(){
          console.log("Error")
        }
      })
      console.log(promise)
```

The Parse logs show the exact results I want from the Cloud function, but I get this: 
"{"_resolved":false,"_rejected":false,"_resolvedCallbacks":[],"_rejectedCallbacks":[]}

I've tried about 50 different version to fix this. Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

This is another version of the code for cloud function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("maps_request", function(request, response) {
  var maps_url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json';
  var origin = request.params.origin;
  var destination = request.params.destination;
  var waypoint = "via:" + request.params.waypoint;
  var test = []
  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: maps_url,
    params: {
      origin: origin,
      destination: destination,
      waypoints: waypoint,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      durationInTraffic: true
    },
    success: function(directions) {
      var time = directions.data['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration']['value']
      time = time / 60.00
      test.push(time)
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log("Error")
    }
  }).then(function() {
    response.success(test[0])
  }, function (error) {
    response.error("Error2")
  })
});
```

And the call:

```
var test = Parse.Cloud.run('maps_request', {
        origin: String(driverOriginAddress + " " + driverOriginZip),
        destination: String(driverDestinationAddress + " " + driverDestinationZip),
        waypoint: String(driverDestinationAddress + " " + driverDestinationZip)
      })
      console.log("Test: " + test)
```

The httpResponse shows the right value, but still not able to access them or assign to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to wrap `Parse.Cloud.run()` in a promise, as it already returns a promise.

Also in your second example you're calling the cloud function as if it is a **sync** call instead of **async** and looking at the promise instead of the result you want.

Try this:

```
Parse.Cloud.run('maps_request', {
  origin: String(driverOriginAddress + " " + driverOriginZip),
  destination: String(driverDestinationAddress + " " + driverDestinationZip),
  waypoint: String(driverDestinationAddress + " " + driverDestinationZip)
}).then(function (result) {
  // we have the result of the cloud function here, just log it for now
  console.log("Test:", result);
}, function (error) {
  // uh oh!
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That sounds about right - you're logging the value of 'promise' to the console. You have to actually resolve() the promise to have it call your Cloud Function and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

How/where do I resolve the promise? Added another version of the code I've been using that returns a similar response.